# PHP exec ZIP with password

Tags: php, exec

Ok Guys I am working on it since yesterday, and this is driving me crazy.

I am creating a way to upload and zip a file on the fly, but also this zip should be then password protected (customer request, unfortunately).

Now everything is fine until the password protection, that is not working at all.

I know exec is so unsafe, but trust me, I just want to have a solution right now.

This is the code

```
if(isset($_FILES['fileSound']['name']) && isset($_FILES['fileLyric']['name'])) {
$nameFileSound = $_FILES['fileSound']['name'];
$tmpNameSound = $_FILES['fileSound']['tmp_name'];
$nameFileLyric = $_FILES['fileLyric']['name'];
$tmpNameLyric = $_FILES['fileLyric']['tmp_name'];
$download_folder = './CopyrightFiles/';
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$fileconpress = $download_folder .  $RefNum . ".zip";

$conpress = $zip->open($fileconpress, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
if ($conpress === true)
{

    $zip->addFile($tmpNameSound, $nameFileSound);
    $zip->addFile($tmpNameLyric, $nameFileLyric);
    $zip->close(); 
    echo $fileconpress."<br/>";
    echo "yess !! Success!!!! ";
}
else echo " Oh No! Error";
}

exec("zip -r ".$download_folder.$RefNum.".zip -P password ".$download_folder.$RefNum."-protected.zip");
```

Now `$RefNum` is a string like this 1333-COP-3899827399283.

I checked if the command exec is up on the server and yes it is.

No errors show up.

What am I doing wrong?

Maybe the path?

What path should I use for the exec command?

For example the $zip option start from the public_html

Where the exec starts?

Do you think is that the problem or is there any other issue?

Please help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing you need to change the argument order:

```
exec("zip -P password $download_folder$RefNum-protected.zip $Orig.zip");
```

Btw there seems no way with the common Unix `zip` command to update the zip file. You will repackage the original zip file as another password-protected zip file here.

If that fails, then look into the `error.log` for clues. Or use `print exec(...)` after adding `2>&1` behind the command to see all error messages.

Comment: Scusami Mario ma devo fare qualcos altro per farlo funzionare? Io sto impazzendo..giuro!

Comment: Non mi parlano quella lingua.

Comment: Ups sorry, your name is typically italian and you come from Europe as stated in your account. Sorry again. It still does not work. And it is driving me crazy. Can you tell me the path that should I use for the exec command. If I echo exec("ls"); it shows xmlrpc

Comment: There should normally be no need for a path. But `exec("which zip")` can clarify that. Else try `print exec("/usr/bin/zip -h2 2>&1");`

Comment: sh: /usr/bin/zip: No such file or directory  That is the answer. What does that mean?

Comment: Contact your hosting provider. They seemingly don't have it installed. (That's the default location, it's unlikely to reside anywhere else on modern Linux distributions.)

Comment: I installed it and I am getting this error now -e encrypt -n don't compress these suffixes

Comment: That's the help text, not the error message. Use `system()` instead of `exec()`.